# What should I do with SQLAlchemy NameError: Name 'db' is not defined

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am building a web app with Flask and SQLAlchemy. I can't seem to find out the reason for this error NameError: name'db' is not defined Would really appreciate your help.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db=SQLAlchemy()
app=Flask(__name__)

#create a function that creates a web application
# a web server will run this web application
def create_app():
    app.debug=True
    app.secret_key='BetterSecretNeeded123'

    #set the app configuration data 
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='sqlite:///bcib.sqlite'

     #initialize db with flask app
    db.init_app(app)

    bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
    
    #importing modules here to avoid circular references, register blueprints of routes
    from . import views
    app.register_blueprint(views.bp)
    #from . import admin
    #app.register_blueprint(admin.bp)
   
    return app

@app.errorhandler(404) 
# inbuilt function which takes error as parameter 
def not_found(e): 
  return render_template("404.html")

@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_error(e):
  return render_template("500.html")
```

When I try to input db.session.add(c1) in my terminal the error occurs

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'db' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

Here the specific documentation : [flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/#factories-extensions)

There is two ways to init the db :

you can binding the instance to a very specific Flask application like this

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

you can create the object once and configure the application later to support :

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
*/
* Your code 
/*
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.init_app(app) # HERE you need to call an init_app

return app
```

so in your case the best way is the second solution with the add of

```
db.init_app(app)
```

if you choose this solution, it will work normally.